# React 16.8 hooks => how to properly inject an array of elements into the DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React's hooks (version 16.8.6) to inject an array of buttons with their respective index + value + onClick={}.

#### Basic code for brevity

```
function App() {
   const [rooms, setRoomArray] = useState([]);
   const roomArray = [
     'room1',
   'room2',
   'room3',
   'room4',
  ];
        
   const handleNewMessage = (room) => {
       setRoomArray(roomArray);
       roomSpawner(rooms);
   };
        
   const test = () =>{
       console.log('test here');
   }
        
   const roomSpawner = (rooms) =>{
        return rooms.map((value,index) => (
            <button onClick={test()} key={index}>{value}</button>
        ));
};
```

Everything works and displays properly, yet by console logging, I see that my console is [going into a loop](https://image.prntscr.com/image/m7U47sMYQVGXG6wKltdINg.png) there is a loop and i'm trying to understand:

1. Is this is a loop or is it react's regular polling/reactive behavior?
2. Is this 'expensive' in terms of performance?
3. Would it make sense to insert into `test()` a socket connection polling a remote server?
4. Am I misusing the construct? If so please show me how to properly inject an array of elements.

Comment: replace `test()` with `test` in your `onClick`. You want to pass in a reference to the click handler, not its return value.

Comment: Can you share what you are returning from the component ? Also try replacing `onClick={test()}` with `onClick={test}` as onClick handler must be a function, not its invocation (unless it returns another function).

Comment: @Chris - thanks, yes that's correct, but still, i'm wondering about this constant loop, if you can elaborate on that and maybe set an answer of how to properly set/get an array in the functional component.

Comment: It doesn't seem you need hooks at all. Can you share a bit more code?

Comment: @Hi Edan, I would prefer to focus on understanding hooks, can you see if you can answer 1-4? toda! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Q1: Is this is a loop or is it react's regular polling/reactive behavior?**

**Answer:** As commenters have pointed out, the loop is being caused by `onClick={test()}`. The `onClick` prop expects a function, and not a function call, to attach as an event handler. What it you can do is something like this:

```
const test = (index) =>{
  console.log('I was called for room number: ' + index);
}

const roomSpawner = (rooms) =>{
  return rooms.map((value,index) => (
    <button onClick={() => test(index)} key={index}>{value}</button>
  ));
```

**Q2: Is this 'expensive' in terms of performance?**

Not at all. This is a perfect valid React implementation.

**Q3: Would it make sense to insert into test() a socket connection polling a remote server?**

I don't think so. You should insert your socket connection inside a `useEffect()` hook to be connected on mount. Something like this:

```
// INSIDE YOUR COMPONENT

useEffect(()=> {
  // CONNECT TO SOCKET
  // ON SOCKET MESSAGES, UPDATE SOME STATE WITH THE NEW ROOMS AND COMPONEN WILL RE-RENDER
  return () => {
    // DISCONNECT FROM SOCKET
  }
},[]); // WITH THIS EMPTY ARRAY, THIS EFFECT WILL RUN ON 1ST RENDER, AND IT WILL DISCONECT FROM YOUR SOCKET WHEN IT GETS DISMOUNTED
```

[React DOCS on useEffect()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

**Q4: Am I misusing the construct? If so please show me how to properly inject an array of elements.**

I think you're fine. Keep the array of rooms in a state variable using `useState()` and use `stateWithArrayOfRooms.map()` to generate your components (buttons, or whatever). Something like.

```
// INSIDE YOUR COMPONENT

const [roomsArray, setRoomsArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
  // CONNECT TO YOUR SOCKET AND UPDATE roomsArray with new messages.
  // setRoomsArray('newRoomsArray from socket');
  return () => {
    // DISCONNECT FROM SOCKET
  }
},[]);

const roomItems = roomsArray.map((item, index) => 
  <RoomComponent key={index or some other unique id} onClick={()=>test(index)}/>
);

return (
  <RoomsContainer>
    {roomItems}
  </RoomsContainer>
);
```